# || Operator, return when result is known?

Tags: ruby, short-circuiting

I have a function similar to the following:

```
def check
  return 2 == 2 || 3 != 2 || 4 != 5
end
```

My question is, will Ruby perform all the comparisons even though the first is true, and thus the function return true. My checks are much more intensive, so I'd like to know if I should break this out in a different way to avoid making all the checks every time.

```
irb(main):004:0> 2 == 2 || 3 != 2 || 4 != 5
=> true
```

Thank you.

Comment: Btw: You don't need the `return` in your method.

Answer (score 17):

Ruby uses [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

This applies to both || and &&.

- With `||` the right operand is not evaluated if the left operand is truthy.
- With `&&` the right operand is not evaluated if the left operand is falsy.

Answer (score 6):

`||` short-circuits as soon as the first condition is true. So yes, it will help if you put the most expensive conditions at the end.

Answer (score 2):

|| will by default short-circuit evaluate, meaning that once the first "true" expression is encountered it will stop evaluation (unless you explicitly state you want all expressions to evaluate with the 'or' operator).

reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 0):

As soon as one of the condition is true, the function will return.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it yourself in irb, like this:

```
irb> p('Hello') || p('World')
```

As we know the function `p` prints its parameters(in an `inspect` manner) then returns them, so if the `||` short circuits, only `"Hello"` is printed, otherwise both `"Hello"` and `"World"` are printed.

You can also test the logical `&&` operator, by using `puts` instead of `p`, as `puts` always returns `nil`.

BTW, irb is a perfect place to play around ruby. You can test everything there, except a small portion of concurrency.